# angular ng-if in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have this template in my directive

```
...     
template:

    "<div class='dd caretImg'>" +
       "<div class='display-field '>{{selectedValue[displayField]}}</div>" +
        "<ul>" +
          "<li ng-repeat='item in data' ng-click='selectItem(item)'>" +
            "<span class='checkOn' ng-if='item.value == model'></span>" +
            "<span class='check' ng-if='item.value != model'></span>" +
              "{{item[displayField]}}" +
          "</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
    "</div>",

....
```

I need the ng-if instead of item.value to have item[displayField] but this:

```
ng-if='item[displayField]== model'
```

is not working.  (it is working fine like this:

```
"{{item[displayField]}}" +
```

(the line above the "" +)  but not inside the ng-if.

The [displayField] is a variable inside the directive.  It is entered in the html attrs.

```
<hover-dropdown
        placeholder   = "select..."
        data          = "comparisons"
        model         = "filter.comparison"
        display-field = "label"
        value-field   = "value"
        style         = "width: 65px;"
        on-select     = "changeFilterField(filter)"
        ></hover-dropdown>
```

I have tried the following variations with no success.

```
ng-if='item[displayField] == model'
ng-if='item[{{displayField}}] == model'
ng-if='item{{[displayField]}} == model'
ng-if='{{item[displayField]}}== model'
```

does anyone know how to do this?

here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/basomupubo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you debug by adding `{{model}}` into your `"{{item[displayField]}}"` line and see if the two values match?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I added a jbin with the example.  see the above

Comment: What is demo supposed to show? It doesn't have same code as question. would help to scale this down to nothing but the specific problem `ng-if`

Comment: the css names are a bit different but the functionality it exactly the same like the code above.  (the jbin was an eariler version of my css).  on the jbin, look inside the directive template the 2 span tags with the ng-if.  change the  ng-if='item.value...', to ng-if='item[displayfield]...' and you will see that it is not working. I am trying to find out how item[displayField] can work inside an ng-if.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake.  i had the wrong field typed.  ng-if=item[somevariable] works as expected.  Thank you for all that took a look at it.